# fread() causes Valgrind error: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

Tags: c, valgrind

**The problem:**

Loading the data in works, but when trying to retrieve the stored text_ from a node valgrind throws an "conditional jump". The text_ is still retrieved correctly and displayed.

**What causes the problem:**

This is code snippet is part of the readFile() function and this particular fread() causes the problem.

```
int readFile(char **text, ...)
    ...
    size_text = filesize - previous_position;
    *text = (char *)malloc(size_text + 1);
    fread(*text, 1, size_text, input);
```

Valgrind Message:

```
==18139== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18139==    at 0x48303C7: __GI_strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:455)
==18139==    by 0x48EA17F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==18139==    by 0x48EF955: printf (printf.c:33)
==18139==    by 0x108F6A: game (version-3.c:243)
==18139==    by 0x109085: main (version-3.c:287)
==18139==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==18139==    at 0x482D27C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==18139==    by 0x108BBC: readFile (version-3.c:125)
==18139==    by 0x108D4A: BuildTree (version-3.c:197)
==18139==    by 0x109074: main (version-3.c:286)
==18139==
```

**Solution**

Adding a null terminator fixes this error.
The initial assumption, that it was already null terminated came from the wrong placing of the null terminator  *text[size_text] = '\0'; -> throws error
(*text)[size_text] = '\0'; -> fixes the error

Comment: check that fread is reading the number of bytes you expect. You are expecting size_text bytes. Is that the amount you read. If you read less then you will get this error

Comment: cos u do some fancy twiddling to determine size_text

Comment: You allocate `size_text + 1` bytes, but only read `size_text` bytes with the `fread`. So that does leave one byte uninitialized.

Comment: So, where do you zero-terminate the string you read by `fread(*text, 1, size_text, input)`?

Comment: @pm100 my fancy twiddling is correct (Read = 381, Calculated = 381), but as it turns out I made a even more basic mistake and placed the null terminator wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error does not happen *in* `fread()`. It happens in `__GI_strlen`. What it means is that a variable which that function depends on for its logic is either not or not fully initialised.

Because you know what `*strlen` is supposed to do (count the number of characters, excepting the terminating `\0` in a C string), you can infer what the problem is: you have `malloc()`'ed a particular size buffer, but your string including the `\0` terminator does not fully occupy it. So there is trailing space in the buffer which is left unitialised, hence the error.

So it would be a good idea to check the return value `fread()` to confirm exactly how many bytes were read. It is not guaranteed to read as many elements (bytes in your case) as you ask for: it can return you an error, or read any number of elements *up to* the limit which you specified.

And it would be another good idea to explicitly place the null terminator in your buffer! (You're missing it.)

Comment: I added the null terminator again and noticed where I made my initial mistake. Instead of  (*text)[size_text] = '\0'; I used *text[size_text] = '\0'; which caused an error and made me believe that a null terminator already exists, despite the fread() explicitly not adding one.